# Fetching number via python

Tags: python, serial-port, at-command

I am communicating to serial ports via python. I passed an AT command to list the phone directory. Now I need to fetch the phone number I received. How do I fetch that particular number via python.

```
+CMGR: "REC READ","+911234567890",,"13/05/31,10:00:14+22"
```

Comment: By "fetch" do you mean "parse"?

Comment: Fetching as in printing the output.

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
>>> import re
>>> strs = '+CMGR: "REC READ","+911234567890",,"13/05/31,10:00:14+22'
>>> re.search(r'"(\+91\d+)"', strs).group(1)
'+911234567890'
>>>
```

Comment: import serial
from curses import ascii
import re

ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=3)
response=ser.write('AT+CMGR=3\r\n')
re.search(r'"(\+91\d+)"', response).group(1)

This isn't working either

Answer (score 1):

If the number is always the nth field, then:

```
s = '+CMGR: "REC READ","+911234567890",,"13/05/31,10:00:14+22"'
import csv
print next(csv.reader([s]))[1]
# +911234567890
```

Comment: import serial
from curses import ascii

ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=3)
response=ser.write('AT+CMGR=3\r\n')
import csv
print next(csv.reader([response]))[1]

This isn't working.